display-dependency-updates tells me there is a new version, but update-properties doesn't touch it
The report shows there are new versions:
 
[INFO] The following dependencies in Dependencies have newer versions:
[INFO]   com.google.dagger:dagger .............................. 2.52 -> 2.53.1

but the doesn't even consider the dagger.version property:
[INFO] --- versions:2.18.0:update-properties (default-cli) @ server ---
[INFO] Property ${jooq.version}: Leaving unchanged as 3.19.16

display-property-updates also ignores it:
[INFO] The following version properties are referencing the newest available version:
[INFO]   ${jooq.version} ............................................. 3.19.16

The property is defined in the same way as the jooq.version that is processed correctly.
        <dagger.version>2.52</dagger.version>
        <jooq.version>3.19.16</jooq.version>

what is the reason? How can I make the update-properties goal update it.
I'm using a property to keep the version, because you can't manage plugin dependencies via dependencyManagement (and you need to add dagger to your compiler plugin).
The difference between dagger.version and jooq.version is that I use dagger.version to set regular dependency version and in configuration of kotlin-maven-plugin; I use jooq.version to set regular and plugin dependency versions.
Could using the property in configuration of plugin be the reason that versions is ignoring it?
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>${jvm.release}</jvmTarget>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xcontext-receivers</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>kapt</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                                    <version>${dagger.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

Reported as https://github.com/mojohaus/versions/issues/1200

are you sure if it is the same property ... please try mvn versions:display-property-updates 

@SlawomirJaranowski I've updated the answer

ok I see you use property dagger.version only for dependencies in custom configuration for ktlin-m-plugin in annotationProcessorPaths ... so version-m-p doesn't know that such configuration is a dependencies .....

we can discuss this as issue in plugin project: https://github.com/mojohaus/versions/issues

@SlawomirJaranowski no I also use it as a regular dependency version

please prepare a simple project which reproduce it attache to issue

it's done and done
